# Kafka - How to link external jar to Kafka's classpath?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have created a jar containing class files used for SASL callbacks and is present in my application directory.

Is there a way to link this jar with Kafka start up (using *kafka-server-start.sh* script) without having to explicitly copy this jar under Kafka's *libs* directory?

Environment: RHEL

Answer (score 0):

You can export the CLASSPATH variable prior to running kafka-server-start, or you can simply symlink the file